# mount: /dev/mapper/centos-home: can't read superblock

Tags: linux, server, centos, mount, home-directory

I've a very big problem. Today after 3 months of activity on my home server I shutdown it and restarted it. It boot in recovery mode. I see from journalctl logs that the problem was:

```
can't mount /home
```

I edited /etc/fstab and insert the 'nofail' flag under the /home row.
Now it starts fine but when I try to launch the following command:

```
mount /home
```

The following error appear:

```
mount: /dev/mapper/centos-home: can't read superblock
```

Could you please help me?
All worked fine before the shutdown and I could access at the /home partition
Thanks Davide

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I resolved the problem. If someone occurs in this problem the following command saved my life:

```
xfs_repair /dev/mapper/centos-home -L
```